# Spring 5 "No LookupPath attribute" exception

Tags: spring, angular, spring-restcontroller

Having a Spring rest controller which use Spring 5 router functions
When I use Postman client to make a request, every thing works fine. 
However making a request from another origin which is Angular 4 application cause this exception.

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: No LookupPath attribute.
>       at org.springframework.web.server.support.LookupPath.lambda$getCurrent$1(LookupPath.java:106) ~[spring-web-5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
>       at java.util.Optional.orElseThrow(Optional.java:290) ~[na:1.8.0_72]
>       at org.springframework.web.server.support.LookupPath.getCurrent(LookupPath.java:106) ~[spring-web-5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
>       at org.springframework.web.cors.reactive.UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource.getCorsConfiguration(UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource.java:84) ~[spring-web-5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
>       at org.springframework.web.reactive.handler.AbstractHandlerMapping.lambda$getHandler$1(AbstractHandlerMapping.java:163) ~[spring-webflux-5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]

```
@RestController
public class AdminRest {
public RouterFunction<ServerResponse> route() {
    return RouterFunctions
            .route(RequestPredicates.GET("/admin/orgnaizationUsers"), this::getOrgnaizationUsers)
}      

private Mono<ServerResponse> getOrgnaizationUsers(ServerRequest request) {
    return Mono
            .just(request)
            .then(
                    Flux.from(organizationUserPostgresCollection.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM organization_user"))
                    .map(OrganizationUserDTO::convert)
                    .collectList()
                    .map(OrganizationUsersDTOView::new))
            .flatMap(
                    organizationUsersDTOView -> ServerResponse.ok().header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
                            .body(Mono.just(organizationUsersDTOView), OrganizationUsersDTOView.class))
            .switchIfEmpty(ServerResponse.notFound().header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*").build());
} 
}
```

Please check 
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/commit/cf1bc8119999e2bf3f41ae572f5b83536685ce5e

Comment: Could be me but shouldn't the `RouterFunction` be a `@Bean` method in a `@Configuration` class?

Comment: Already exist.


   `@Configuration
    public class RESTConfiguration {
    
        @Bean
        public RouterFunction<ServerResponse> adminRoute(AdminRest 
    adminRest) {
            return adminRest.route();
        }
    }`

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the issue arises when UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource tries to retrieve the LookupPath before it has been initialized. You can get around of this, for now at least, by adding a new Webfilter in your application that creates the lookup path.

This can be done like this for example:

```
@Component
public class SomeFilter extends WebFilter {
    @Override
    public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, WebFilterChain chain) {
        LookupPath.getOrCreate(exchange, new HttpRequestPathHelper());
        return chain.filter(exchange);
    }
 }
```